# Java- Read from a .csv file and compute avg

Tags: java, arrays, csv

How do I read a .csv Excel file with x number of rows and y number of columns, ignore irrelevant cells (things like names, or empty cells), then compute an average of the numbers in relevant cells?

I have managed to read a simple txt file, which looks like this:
[image: I have managed to read a simple txt file, which looks like this]

Works fine with this, I get all the relevant info I need, but when I try to get data from a .csv file, it returns back the IOException

This is the .csv file:
[image: This is the .csv file]

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * Station name, read from input file
     */
    private static String stationid = null;

    /**
     * Set of records, read from input file
     */
    private static ArrayList<StationRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();


    /**
     * @param year
     */
    public static void listMaxWindByYear(int year) {
        records.sort((o1, o2) -> (o2.getMaxWind() - o1.getMaxWind()));

        System.out.println("Max Wind by the Station during " + year);
        System.out.printf("%-40s%-15s%-20s\n", "Station Name", "Max Wind", "Date");
        System.out.printf("%-40s%-15s%-20s\n", "------------", "--------", "----");

        int maxWind = records.get(0).getMaxWind();
        for (StationRecord record : records) {
            if (record.getMaxWind() == maxWind) {
                System.out.printf("%-40s%-15d%-20s\n", stationid, record.getMaxWind(),
                                  record.getMonth() + " " + record.getDay() + ", " + record.getYear());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

   
    public static void listMinWindByYear(int year) {
        records.sort((o1, o2) -> (o1.getMinWind() - o2.getMinWind()));

        System.out.println("Min Wind by the Station during " + year);
        System.out.printf("%-40s%-15s%-20s\n", "Station Name", "Min Wind", "Date");
        System.out.printf("%-40s%-15s%-20s\n", "------------", "--------", "----");

        int minWind = records.get(0).getMinWind();
        for (StationRecord record : records) {
            if (record.getMinWind() == minWind) {
                System.out.printf("%-40s%-15d%-20s\n", stationid, record.getMinWind(),
                                  record.getMonth() + " " + record.getDay() + ", " + record.getYear());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    
    public static double calculateAverageOfAverageWindByYear(int year) {
        double total = 0;
        int numRecords = 0;

        for (StationRecord record : records) {
            if (record.getYear() == year) {
                total += record.getAverageWind();
                numRecords++;
            }
        }

        if (numRecords == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return total / numRecords;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param args Unused arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        File inputFile = null;
        Scanner menuScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please, enter input file name:");
                inputFile = new File(menuScanner.nextLine());
                parseFile(inputFile);
                menuScanner.close();
                                break;
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("File Name you entered is not relevant");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        
       
        listMaxWindByYear(2019);

       
        listMinWindByYear(2019);

        
        double overallAverageTemp = calculateAverageOfAverageWindByYear(2019);
        System.out.println(stationid + " average Wind: " + String.format("%.1f", overallAverageTemp));
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void parseFile(File file) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            stationid = scanner.nextLine();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                records.add(new StationRecord(scanner.nextLine()));
            }
            scanner.close();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            scanner.close();
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            scanner.close();
            throw new IOException();
        }


    }
```

So summary of what it is intended to do, read the columns with windspeed list max and min values and calculate an average print on screen or file (only can do screen print at the mom).
Next step would be
Calculating monthly average, min, max of each year And Print to File .

I hope this is understandable and something I can get help with, I am really new to java and every help would be much appreciated.
Feel free to edit my code or lecture if necessary.

Comment: What does the exception say? In 99% of the cases, this is enough to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: When you type the file name are you typing the full path or just the file name? If just file name what happens when you type the full path?

Comment: only type the filename and when i read the txt file i get the data back, with csv i get the exception "File Name you entered is not relevant" , if i type in the full path still get the same Exception